# Node js to mongoose CastError: Cast to date failed for value "{ '$gte': 2013-12-12T16:00:00.000Z

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Code :

```
module.exports.updateInformation = function(callback){  
    test.update({'test':''}, {
        'created_at': {
            '$gte': new Date('2013-12-12T16:00:00.000Z'),//new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-2)),
            '$lte': new Date('2018-12-12T16:00:00.000Z') //new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-1))
        }
    }, callback);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to recheck the docs of mongoose for the update method.
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update

The first parameter is the condition-object. In your case:

```
'created_at': {
   '$gte': new Date('2013-12-12T16:00:00.000Z'),//new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-2)),
   '$lte': new Date('2018-12-12T16:00:00.000Z') //new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-1))
}
```

The second parameter is the doc you want to update.
For example (from docs):

`Tank.update({ _id: id }, { $set: { size: 'large' }}, callback);`

Hope this helps you understanding your mistake.

Comment: yes, you are right i have  put the condition in second part rather than first place.